# Scrapy: Extract Dictionary Stored as Text in Script Tag

Tags: python, scrapy, abstract-syntax-tree

Subject: Extract Dictionary Stored in Script Tag.

Hello,

I am trying to scrape this data from the  tag.

[image]

The goal is to be able to extract the data dictionary and get the values for each of the key value pairs.

```
Example:
print(digitalData['page']['pageInfo']['language'])
>>> en
```

I have written the code below and everything works until get to step 3 where  I try to convert the string to a dictionary using the ast module.

I get the following error message:

```
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x00000238C9100B48>
```

Scrapy Code

```
import scrapy
import re
import pprint
import ast


class OptumSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'optum'
    allowed_domains = ['optum.com']
    start_urls = ['http://optum.com/']

    def parse(self, response):


        #Step 1: remove all spaces, new lines and tabs
        #string = (re.sub('\s+','',response.xpath('//script/text()')[2].extract()))
        string = (re.sub('[\s+;]','',response.xpath('//script/text()')[2].extract()))
        print(string)


        # Step 2: convert string to dictionary. Creates a key as "digitalData"
        key, value = string.split("=")
        my_dict = {key: value}
        print(my_dict)

        # Step 3: extract dictionary 
        print(my_dict['digitalData']) # result is a dictionary stored as a string.
        print(type(my_dict['digitalData']))  # shows data type as string.
        #ast.literal_eval(my_dict['digitalData']) # convert string to dictionary.
```

I get the following error message:

```
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x00000238C9100B48>
```

Please provide comments on how to solve.  If there is another way to approach or solve please suggest.

Comment: You need to include your entire code or at the very lease a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @FelipeFaria That is the entire set of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that within the extracted Javascript dictionary: you have objects.

```js
{
 page: {
  pageInfo: {
   destinationURL: window.location.href,
   error: '',
   language: 'en',
   country: 'US',
   pageName: 'tangelo2',
   articlepubdate: '',
   articleenddate: '',
   pageTitle: 'HealthServicesInnovationCompany',
   pageOwner: '',
   pageTemplate: '',
   pageCampaign: '',
   tags: '',
   pageLastPublishDate: '2020-01-08T12:15:04.032-06:00',
   pageLastPublishedBy: 'admin',
   pageLastModifiedDate: '2020-01-08T10:24:36.466-06:00',
   pageLastModifiedBy: 'katrina'
  },
  recEngine: {
   title: 'Home',
   image: '',
   description: ''
  },
  category: {
   siteName: window.location.hostname.replace("www.", ""),
   version: '3.0',
   contentType: '',
   contentTopic: '',
   contentSegment: '',
   contentInitiative: '',
   contentProduct: '',
   contentProductLine: '',
   primaryCategory: 'tangelo2'
  }
 },
 event: {}
}
```

Notice the `page.pageInfo.destinationURL` as well as the `page.category.siteName` values.

What is going on is that `ast.literal_eval` or any other method you might try to convert this Javascript dictionary to Python will result in an error. You'll need to find a way to remove the `window...` from the `my_dict['digitalData']` before processing it via `ast`, `demjson`, or any other tool.

---

A possible solution is one like so, utilizing [`demjson`](https://pypi.org/project/demjson/) as oppose to `ast`.

```py
import scrapy
import pprint
import demjson
import re


class OptumSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'optum'
    allowed_domains = ['optum.com']
    start_urls = ['http://optum.com/']

    def parse(self, response):


        #Step 1: remove all spaces, new lines and tabs
        string = (re.sub('[\s+;]','',response.xpath('//script/text()')[2].extract()))

        # Step 2: convert string to dictionary. Creates a key as "digitalData"
        js_dict = string.split("=")[1]
        js_dict = re.sub(r"\bwindow(.*?),\b", '"",', js_dict)

        # Step 3: extract dictionary
        my_dict = demjson.decode(js_dict)

        pprint.pprint(my_dict)
        print(type(my_dict))
```

On running

```
scrapy runspider test.py -s LOG_ENABLED=False
```

It outputs:

```
{'event': {},
 'page': {'category': {'contentInitiative': '',
                       'contentProduct': '',
                       'contentProductLine': '',
                       'contentSegment': '',
                       'contentTopic': '',
                       'contentType': '',
                       'primaryCategory': 'tangelo2',
                       'siteName': '',
                       'version': '3.0'},
          'pageInfo': {'articleenddate': '',
                       'articlepubdate': '',
                       'country': 'US',
                       'destinationURL': '',
                       'error': '',
                       'language': 'en',
                       'pageCampaign': '',
                       'pageLastModifiedBy': 'katrina',
                       'pageLastModifiedDate': '2020-01-08T10:24:36.466-06:00',
                       'pageLastPublishDate': '2020-01-08T12:15:04.032-06:00',
                       'pageLastPublishedBy': 'admin',
                       'pageName': 'tangelo2',
                       'pageOwner': '',
                       'pageTemplate': '',
                       'pageTitle': 'HealthServicesInnovationCompany',
                       'tags': ''},
          'recEngine': {'description': '', 'image': '', 'title': 'Home'}}}
<class 'dict'>
```

Comment: Glad it did! :)